# Proper punctuation with contractions at the closing parenthesis

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need the period here right after the closing parenthesis?

> Он торговал только фруктами (яблоками, грушами, апельсинами, и **т.п.).**
>   Приближалась осень.

Or should I, perhaps, drop the dots in the "т.п." contraction? Like here:

> Он торговал только фруктами (яблоками, грушами, апельсинами, и **тп**).
>   Приближалась осень.

Comment: What you *do not* need here is the comma after *апельсинами*. Russian list punctuation avoids the Oxford comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in case of parentheses at the end of the sentence after contractions, the period is needed (also, you can't omit periods in contractions like you did in your second example). The period, however, is not doubled if there are no parentheses. Some examples from [this source](http://www.ufanabor.ru/pages/art8_mainrule.html):

> В магазин поступила обувь: калоши, сапоги, валенки **и др.**
>
> В магазин поступили игрушки: неваляшки (50 шт.), машинки заводные (15 шт.), пистолеты пластмассовые **(157 шт.).**